# How to pass <(box unsigned-int)> to com-invoke?

Tags: com, scheme, racket, win32ole

My try:

```
(com-invoke fsc "Connect" "" (box +0))
```

exact error:

```
Connect: expected argument of type <(box unsigned-int)>; given: '#&0
```

How to pass <(box unsigned-int)> to com-invoke?

Comment: What object type is fsc?

Comment: @benrudgers `(define fsc (com-create-instance "dcomobj.1"))`

Comment: `com-invoke` works on `IDispatch` objects, so the particular method you're calling matters (like, I actually need to see its actual IDL definition). Is the ProgID _really_ `dcomobj.1`? If so, is this a custom COM object you wrote yourself, or is it easily obtainable?

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young The name suggests it is a DCOM object rather than a COM object. The Racket documentation suggests there are additional concerns: http://docs.racket-lang.org/foreign/com-auto.html?q=com-invoke#%28part._remote%29

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young it's custom object I wrote myself. `[id(DISPID_CONNECT)] HRESULT Connect([in] BSTR bstrId, [in, out] DWORD *dw);`